# What is platform independent way of converting csv files to tsv files if the csv files can be quoted with comma inside the quoted strings?

Tags: perl, sed, awk, csv

Suppose I have a csv file like this

```
a,b,c
1,"drivingme,mad",2
```

and I want convert it to a TSV

```
a<tab>b<tab>c
1<tab>drivingme,mad<tab>2
```

Whilst I can write some Python code to do this. I found this to be slow. Is there a better awk, sed or perl way that is quite fast even if the number of rows runs into the millions?

I need to do this as I can't import the CSV file into a SQLite database with the above csv as SQLite has limited csv import facilities.

Comment: @ikegami - if I had a penny for every time I mistyped CSV and CVS instead of each other ... :)

Comment: If you want the data to end up in a database, why the TSV-detour?

Comment: @innaM, I suspect that massive imports will be faster through the TSV import mechanism than through DBI. A lot faster.

Comment: how else can you import potentially gigabyte size csv files into sqlite?

Answer (score 6):

[`Text::CSV_XS`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS) (XS is the C version of the module, and is faster than native Perl Text::CSV) is the usual tool of choice. It

- handles quoted (and comma containing) fields easily
- can be used for both reading and writing
- Can switch between delimiters so you can have a writer object using TAB.

**Example (sans error handling):**

```
my $csv_in = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 });
my $csv_out = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, sep_char => "\t", eol => "\n" });
open my $fh_in, "<", "file_in.csv" or die "file_in.csv: $!";
open my $fh_out, ">", "file_out.csv" or die "file_out.csv: $!";

while (my $row = $csv_in->getline($fh_in)) {
    $csv_out->print ($fh_out, $row)
}
close $fh_in;
close $fh_out;
```

Comment: I think that Text::CSV uses the XS version if installed, and has done for several years.

Comment: @plusplus - correct. But if not installed, you are better off with another fast solution instea

Comment: This seems like an obvious task to write as a Unix filter program -reading from STDIN and writing to STDOUT. Saves all that tedious mucking about with filehandles :-)

Comment: @DaveCross - The CLI pattern doesn't matter much. I was merely mimicking the OP's original code. BTW, there are CLI design constraints where having an option of passing a filename instead of forcing piping is warranted.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `GNU awk` (version 4.0 or higher) you could do it with this one-liner:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1;gsub(/"/,"")}1' FPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")' OFS='\t' file
a   b   c
1   drivingme,mad   2
```

Comment: +1 for gawk solution. If anyone is interested, FPAT is explained in the [gnu manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html). Obviously. :)

Comment: Minor issue: What if the field contains a double-quotation mark, like `"quotation""nice words"""`

Comment: @TrueY then you would describe you `FPAT` accordingly, as the question is described this solution should do a good job beyond that it's up to the OP to make the required changes.

Comment: In Windows XP I am getting this error. '{$1=$1;gsub(//,")}1' says invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: I am not familiar with the quoting nuances on Windows, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

No need for Text::CSV. [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aParseWords) is part of the standard Perl distribution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<>) {
  print join "\t", parse_line(',', 0, $_);
}
```

Call it as a Unix filter, like this:

```
$ ./csv2tsv < test.csv > test.tsv
```

Answer (score 2):

For large CSV files, I use [Parse::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Parse-CSV-2.00/lib/Parse/CSV.pm). Also, you can combine with [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.627/DBI.pm) + [DBD::SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/DBD-SQLite-1.39/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm) to insert the parsed rows from CSV into your SQLite database

Comment: As a note, Parse::CSV uses Text::CSV_XS underneath (but supposedly - can't confirm since I never used it - has an easier to use API)

Comment: +1 for the idea of impporting straight into DB bypassing the file.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(("[^"]*",)*"[^",]+),/\1\n/;ta;s/"//g;y/,\n/\t,/' file
```

Replace `,`'s within `"`'s with `\n`'s. Then delete `"`'s and translate `,`'s and `\n`'s to `\t`'s and `,`'s.